# Why do almost all points in the unit interval have Kolmogorov complexity 1?

Tags: computational-complexity, turing-machines, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure, kolmogorov-complexity

I am reading

- Jin-yi Cai, Juris Hartmanis, [On Hausdorff and topological dimensions of the Kolmogorov complexity of the real line](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0000(05)80073-X), Journal of Computer and System Sciences, Volume 49, Issue 3, December 1994.

and I am having a difficult time figuring out an argument they say is obvious.

Define a function $K(x)$ on the unit interval to be $$K(x)=\liminf_{n \to \infty} K(x_n)/n,$$ where $K(x_n)$ is the information constant of $x_n$, the first $n$ bits of $x$ (i.e., the size in bits of the smallest program which will cause a fixed universal Turing machine to produce $x_n$). They make the claim that the set of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $K(x)=1$ has full measure. Why is this? I see that by translation/scaling invariance by rational numbers, it either must have full or zero measure, but I can't make an argument why it must have positive measure. They say it is by a "simple counting argument," which I don't understand.

Note: I re-posted this question to MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435010/why-do-almost-all-points-in-the-unit-interval-have-kolmogorov-complexity-1), where I got a satisfactory answer thanks to Ronnie Pavlov.

Comment: Is $x_n$ the first $n$ bits of $x$?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Yes, I just edited the question appropriately.

Comment: Crossposted to MathOverflow: [Why do almost all points in the unit interval have Kolmogorov complexity 1?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/435010).